# How to replace '|' in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have too many records which ending as below :

> en-US|||||

But i wanted them to be replace to new line let say

> en-US
>
> newline

Note text en and US are different in each records, the only item needed to be kept is "-".
Please advise.

Comment: The only thing method i tried is replace with : \n. What do i have to input in "Find What : xx-xx||||" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (Find & Replace).
2. Use those settings:

   - Search mode: `Extended`
   - *Find what:* `|||||`
   - *Replace with:* `\n`
3. Replace.

Answer (score 2):

User regular expression to find 
`[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]-[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]||||` and replace `\n`

in Notepad++ 6, PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) is supported. Here is [Ref](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html).

We should also referece another stackoverflow question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398613/notepad-newline-in-regex